# My hover popup is flickering and moving when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to create a popup that will show when hovering over an element. However it flickers and moves around when I move my mouse inside the element. It should also stay open if the mouse moves over the popup.
Trying to do this without library cheats like jQuery. You don't learn if you use them.

If you hover your mouse over one of the tags below, that's exactly what I'm trying to create.

Think the error is somewhere in this code:

```
function showPopup(e) {
    var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
    if (popup.style.display == 'none') {
        popup.style.display = 'block';

var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elemRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect(),
    offsetX   = elemRect.left - bodyRect.left,
    offsetY   = elemRect.bottom - bodyRect.top;
        popup.style.left = offsetX + 'px';
        popup.style.top = offsetY + 'px';
        //console.log(e);
    }
}

function hidePopup(/*e*/) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
        if (popup.style.display == 'block' && !window.inside_popup) {
            popup.style.display = 'none';
            window.inside_popup = false;
            console.log('hide');
        } else {
            setTimeout(hidePopup, 50); // try a little later
        }
    }, 50); // Give the events ability to catch up and tell us the mouse is inside the popup
}

var targ = document.querySelector('ul li')
    targ.addEventListener('mouseover', showPopup);
    targ.addEventListener('mouseout', hidePopup);
```

Full javascript code with a real test element:
https://jsfiddle.net/g8wvae8o/

Comment: You need to use mouseenter and mouseleave

Answer (score 0):

As @epascarello said, `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` are what you're looking for.  There's no need for `setTimeout` here either.  In addition, you're targeting every `li` on the page (is that intentional?)  I recommend targeting a specific class of element to reduce flickering.

This is close, but you'll need to massage the positioning.

```
function createPopup() {
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.id = 'popup';
  container.style.width = '500px';
  container.style.height = '700px';
  container.style.display = 'none';
  container.style.position = 'absolute';
  container.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    container.style.border = '1px solid #242729';
    container.style.backgroundColor = '#535a60';
    container.style.color = '#e4e6e8';
    container.style.zIndex = '9999999';
  container.addEventListener('xmouseenter', function() {
    window.inside_popup = true;
    //console.log('window.inside_popup = true;');
  });
  container.addEventListener('xmouseleave', function() {
    window.inside_popup = false;
    //console.log('window.inside_popup = false;');
  });
  container.appendChild(document.createTextNode('This is a test'));
  (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(container);
}
window.inside_popup = false;
createPopup();


function showPopup(e) {
  var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
  if (popup.style.display == 'none') {
    popup.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function hidePopup(/*e*/) {
  console.log('hiding')
  popup.style.display = 'none';
  window.inside_popup = false;
}

var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect()
function updatePopup(e) {
  var elemRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect(),
      offsetY   = elemRect.bottom - bodyRect.top,
      offsetX   = elemRect.left - bodyRect.left;
    popup.style.left = (e.clientX + offsetX) + 'px';
    popup.style.top = offsetY + 'px';
}

var targ = document.querySelector('ul li')
  targ.addEventListener('mouseenter', showPopup);
  targ.addEventListener('mouseleave', hidePopup);
  targ.addEventListener('mousemove', updatePopup)
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mhuvaL3/)

Comment: Each li contains a unique link to the shown product with more detailed information. The hover popup is intended to extract that and display it in the hover popup. If you're curious here's the complete link https://www.systembolaget.se/dryck/ol/1664-blanc-151403

Comment: Apologize for the messy code, thought the mess was readable.
As for the popup, it's supposed to stay stationary right underneath the element just like the tag popup
[tag popup](https://i.imgur.com/mcOJsj1.png)
And the code for extracting the detailed information is already complete. It use XMLHttpRequest with document.implementation.createHTMLDocument, some editing later a part of that page will be inserted into the hover popup via .innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure CSS solution (I only use JS to create the popup elements)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
 var els = document.querySelectorAll("li");
    els.forEach(el => {
     var popup = document.createElement("div");
        popup.innerHTML = el.getAttribute("popup");
        popup.className = "popup";
        el.appendChild(popup);
    });
});
```

```css
*[popup]:hover > .popup {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto
}

.popup {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: black;
    color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
}

li {
    margin: 2em 0
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li popup="Some more info about this product">Move the mouse here</li>
    <li popup="Some more info about the 2nd product">Some other product</li>
</ul>
```

The key to this is that the popup is a child of the element that is hovered, thus moving the mouse over the popup still counts as hovering the element.

Comment: Looks nice and does what I need.. However doesn't properly work on the page (I'm trying to modify) though. Something is interfering. Something makes the popup show up but in the middle of  the element. Extending a site to make it better is hard in this case.

Comment: This is about the positioning; I set the popup to  `absolute`, which puts it right below the `<li>`. Just add `left:` and `top:` properties to the `.popup` rule and experiment with different `px` values.